# Response message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval null

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing, beanshell

while executing in jmeter bean shell sampler we are getting the error as above 
mentioned.

Actually code was working fine in Eclipse but while implement in Jmeter it is not working. 
can any one help us to resolve this issue?

```
import com.google.gson.*;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.*;
import java.util.Set;
public class JsonComparator {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();

    try{
        Gson g = new Gson();
        JsonElement jsonElement1 = parser
                .parse(new FileReader("E:\\InCites_UI\\trunk\\Tests\\Filters_ByPerson_People_PerfC.json"));
        JsonElement jsonElement2 = parser
                .parse(new FileReader("E:\\InCites_UI\\trunk\\Tests\\Filters_ByPerson_People_PerfA.json"));

        System.out.println("Is the two JSON File Same: "+compareJson(jsonElement1, jsonElement2));
        if(!compareJson(jsonElement1, jsonElement2)){
            Type mapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>(){}.getType();
            Map<String,Object> firstMap = g.fromJson(jsonElement1, mapType);
            Map<String, Object> secondMap = g.fromJson(jsonElement2, mapType);
            System.out.println(JsonComparator.mapDifference(firstMap, secondMap));
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("The Two JSON Are SAME!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        }

    }catch(Exception e1){
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public static <K, V> Map<K, V> mapDifference(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> left, Map<? extends K, ? extends V> right) {
    Map<K, V> difference =  new HashMap<K, V>();
    difference.putAll(left);
    difference.putAll(right);
    difference.entrySet().removeAll(right.entrySet());
    return difference;
}

public static boolean compareJson(JsonElement json1, JsonElement json2) {
    boolean isEqual = true;
    ArrayList<Object> ls1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
     ArrayList<Object> ls2 = new ArrayList<Object>();
    // Check whether both jsonElement are not null
    if (json1 != null && json2 != null) {

        // Check whether both jsonElement are objects
        if (json1.isJsonObject() && json2.isJsonObject()) {
            Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> ens1 = ((JsonObject) json1).entrySet();
            Set<Entry<String, JsonElement>> ens2 = ((JsonObject) json2).entrySet();
            JsonObject json2obj = (JsonObject) json2;
            if (ens1 != null && ens2 != null && (ens2.size() == ens1.size())) {
                // Iterate JSON Elements with Key values
                for (Entry<String, JsonElement> en : ens1) {
                    isEqual = isEqual && compareJson(en.getValue(),json2obj.get(en.getKey()));
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        // Check whether both jsonElement are arrays
        else if (json1.isJsonArray() && json2.isJsonArray()) {
            JsonArray jarr1 = json1.getAsJsonArray();
            JsonArray jarr2 = json2.getAsJsonArray();
            if (jarr1.size() != jarr2.size()) {
                return false;
            } else {
                int i = 0;
                // Iterate JSON Array to JSON Elements
                for (JsonElement je : jarr1) {
                    isEqual = isEqual && compareJson(je, jarr2.get(i));
                    i++;
                }
                if (isEqual) {
                    Object[] o1 = ls1.toArray();
                    Object[] o2 = ls2.toArray();
                    isEqual = Arrays.deepEquals(o1, o2);
                }
            }

        }

        // Check whether both jsonElement are null
        else if (json1.isJsonNull() && json2.isJsonNull()) {
            return true;
        }

        // Check whether both jsonElement are primitives
        else if (json1.isJsonPrimitive() && json2.isJsonPrimitive()) {
            ls1.add(json1);
            ls2.add(json2);
        }
    } else if (json1 == null && json2 == null) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    return isEqual;
}
```

}

we are looking for the help on this, If any one can able to use this code and try to work on Jmeter?  we are not able implement in Jmeter.

Actually code was working fine in Eclipse but while implement in Jmeter it is not working.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots of your project, please include the code it self instead, so it is easier to read and copy in case someone wants to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 Beanshell script troubleshooting techniques:

1. Add **[debug();](http://www.beanshell.org/manual/bshcommands.html#debug)** command to the beginning of your script - this way you will get extra information regarding your test flow in [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29)
2. Put your code inside [try block](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) like:

   ```
   try {
       //your code here
   }
   catch (Throwable ex) {
       log.error("Beanshell failure", ex);
       throw ex;
   }
   ```

   taking this approach you will get the way more informative stacktrace in *jmeter.log* file

In general I would recommend switching to [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy](http://groovy-lang.org/) language. [Groovy has built-in JSON support](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html) and performs much better comparing to Beanshell, see [Groovy Is the New Black](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) article for details.

Going forward don't post code as images, I don't think there will be enthusiasts who will dig into this.